# Asserion failed service testing spring

Tags: spring, testing

I have a simple shampoos-warehouse api and want to test it service logic, but something going wrong.
Here's my Service Test:

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ShampooServiceTest {

    public static final String SHAMPOO_NAME = "name";
    public static final int SHAMPOO_CAPACITY = 1000;
    public static final int SHAMPOO_QUANTITY = 30;
    public static final boolean SHAMPOO_IS_HEALTHY = true;
    public static final LocalDate SHAMPOO_EXPIRATION_DATE = LocalDate.parse("2022-11-11");

    public static final String SHAMPOO_PARAM = "equals";


    @Autowired
    ShampooService shampooService;

    @MockBean
    ShampooRepository shampooRepository;

    @Test
    void getAddAndGetTotalShampoosByParams(){
        shampooService.addShampoos(UUID.randomUUID(), SHAMPOO_NAME, SHAMPOO_CAPACITY, SHAMPOO_QUANTITY, SHAMPOO_IS_HEALTHY, SHAMPOO_EXPIRATION_DATE);
        assertEquals(String.valueOf(SHAMPOO_QUANTITY), shampooService.getTotalShampoosByParam(SHAMPOO_NAME, SHAMPOO_CAPACITY, SHAMPOO_PARAM));
    }
```

I have an assertion error here:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :30
Actual   :0
```

Here's my DTO:

```
public class ShampooDto {

public interface IncomeValidation{}
public interface OutcomeValidation{}

@NotNull(groups={IncomeValidation.class, OutcomeValidation.class})
private String name;

@Min(100)
@Max(5000)
@NotNull(groups={IncomeValidation.class, OutcomeValidation.class})
private int capacity;

@NotNull(groups={IncomeValidation.class, OutcomeValidation.class})
private int quantity;

@NotNull(groups={IncomeValidation.class})
private boolean healthy;

@NotNull(groups={IncomeValidation.class})
private LocalDate expiration_date;
}
```

And here's my service:

```
    public String getTotalShampoosByParam(String name, int capacity, String param){
    Integer totalQuantity;
    switch (param){
        case "less":
            totalQuantity = shampooRepository.getTotalQuantityWhereCapacityLess(name, capacity);
            break;
        case "equals":
            totalQuantity = shampooRepository.getTotalQuantityWhereCapacityEquals(name, capacity);
            break;
        case "more":
            totalQuantity = shampooRepository.getTotalQuantityWhereCapacityMore(name, capacity);
            break;
        default:
            totalQuantity = 0;
    }
    if(totalQuantity!=null){
        return String.valueOf(totalQuantity);
    }
    else{
        return "0";
    }

  }

    public Shampoo addShampoos(UUID id, String name, int capacity, int quantity, boolean healthy, LocalDate expiration_date) throws ValidationException {
    Optional<Shampoo> answer = shampooRepository.findShampooByNameAndCapacity(name, capacity);
    if(answer.isPresent()){
        Shampoo shampoo = answer.get();
        shampoo.setQuantity(shampoo.getQuantity() + quantity);
        shampooRepository.save(shampoo);
        return shampoo;
    }
    else{
        Shampoo shampoo = new Shampoo(id, name, capacity, quantity, healthy, expiration_date, LocalDate.now());
        shampooRepository.save(shampoo);
        return shampoo;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I added Shampoos and search it by requests, all works, but my test give me "0" instead of "30"

Comment: you are using the mock of repository, hence nothing is saved. use breakpoints and debug to see what is happening in `getTotalShampoosByParam`

Comment: What I should use instead of mock for correct testing service layer?

Comment: you either mock the calls to DB or you use real DB in tests and populate it with the test data, and us real repository instance in tests